# DJango - NoReverseMatch Error

Tags: python, django, frameworks, django-urls

That is the exception value:
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

index.html

```
<p>Estudiante: <a href="{% url 'polls.views.student_detail' id=student.id %}">{{student.stduent_name}}</a></p>
```

The link should go to a route like this "127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/". The route works fine out of the link.

views.py

```
def student_detail(request, id):
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=id)
    return render(request, 'polls/student_detail.html', {'student': student})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.index),
     url(r'^polls/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/', views.student_detail),
```

]

Images:

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LBfp.png)

[Route tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdrd2.png)

Comment: I don't think that this is the answer, but student_name is spelled wrong.

Comment: I know but not is the fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to the `url` template tag is the "url name". You need to specify a name when you define the route, something like:

```
url(r'^polls/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/', views.student_detail, name='student-detail'),
```

and then update your template to use it like:

```
{% url 'student-detail' id=student.id %}
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url) on the url template and url names.

Answer (score 1):

The template code in the exception is different to the template code you've pasted in your question. The exception indicates your template tag looks like:

```
{% url polls.views.student_detail id=student.id %}
```

Note the missing quotes which is consistent with the exception. Without the quotes django is attempting to resolve polls.views.student_detail as a variable instead of passing it as a string to the template tag. Since it can't resolve you're passing a blank string to your template tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking an url by name but there's no such named url in the urls.py file.

your urlpatterns should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^polls/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/', views.student_detail, name='student_detail'),
]
```

And then in your template:

```
<p>Estudiante: <a href="{% url 'student_detail' student.id %}">{{student.stduent_name}}</a></p>
```

notice that you don't need to explicitly pass the parameter name, Django transforms each parameter separated by space in the respective parameter specified in the url regex pattern.